# How to render list of svgs in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, svg

I have an array of emojis and each emoji has `emoji` and `label` field. I would like to know how to render emoji using map in my component.

I have stored all the emojis as SVG files in the `src/assets/emojiIcons`.

Right now, I'm doing like this:

```
import { ReactComponent as Coin } from "../assets/emojiIcons/coin.svg"
import { ReactComponent as Rocket } from "../assets/emojiIcons/rocket.svg"

const DEFAULT_EMOJI_OPTIONS = [
  {
    emoji: Rocket,
    label: "rocket",
  },
  {
    emoji: Coin,
    label: "coin",
  },
]

export { DEFAULT_EMOJI_OPTIONS }
```

importing the emojis in my component like this:

```
import { DEFAULT_EMOJI_OPTIONS } from "../../utils/emojis"

const EmojiSection = () => {
  return (
    <div className="text-white border-2 border-gray-800 rounded p-3 my-8 max-w-xs mx-auto">
      {DEFAULT_EMOJI_OPTIONS.map((emoji) => (
          <emoji.emoji />
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Is there any better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the `import { ReactComponent as Coin }` syntax only works if you're using create-react-app. If you are, then this is probably the best option, provided you don't need to re-colour the image or anything fancy like that.

If you're not using create-react-app, I'd just use an `img` tag.

You can use `file-loader` to import the svg, rather than needing to keep the path in a string.

In your webpack config (there are similar options for vite or other systems):

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(png|jp(e*)g|svg|gif)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

```
import Coin from "../assets/emojiIcons/coin.svg";

const DEFAULT_EMOJI_OPTIONS = [
  {
    emoji: Coin,
    label: "coin",
  },
  .
  .
  .
];


.
.
.
const EmojiSection = () => {
  return (
    <div className="text-white border-2 border-gray-800 rounded p-3 my-8 max-w-xs mx-auto">
      {DEFAULT_EMOJI_OPTIONS.map((emoji) => (
          <img src={emoji.emoji} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm using create-react-app

Comment: I have one more question. Is it possible to add emoji count dynamically from a database like firebase just below img tag? Basically, I want to render the emoji from a local file and want to add emoji count below the emoji dynamically.

Comment: You would need to have some kind of reference of emoji in firebase like below 
const DEFAULT_EMOJI_OPTIONS = [ { emoji: Coin, emoji_id: 1 } ] and in your firebase database you would need something like {emoji_id:1, count:3}, and when you are rendering the emoji below it you can use the emoji id to get the count from the firebase, I would recommend to fetch the firebase data first and then you can search from local firebase data array.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have this two svg so i tried with string value. You can map  in one component then you can actually render the component. You are using svg as component . While this svgs are images they don't have any export function. In react you easily map all the svgs with the help of  tag.

```
 import  Coin  from "../assets/emojiIcons/coin.svg"
 import Rocket from "../assets/emojiIcons/rocket.svg"

const DEFAULT_EMOJI_OPTIONS = [
  {
    emoji: Rocket,
    label: "rocket",
  },
  {
    emoji: Coin,
    label: "coin",
  },
]

function Test() {
  return (
    <>
      {DEFAULT_EMOJI_OPTIONS.map(({ emoji,label }) => (
        <div >
          <div>
            <img src={emoji} alt="xyz" width={50}/>
            <h2>{label}</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </>
  )
}

export default Test;
```

Answer (score 1):

If your application is using Mui, you can archieve this by SvgIcon.

```
 import  Coin  from "../assets/emojiIcons/coin.svg"
 import Rocket from "../assets/emojiIcons/rocket.svg"
 import { SvgIcon } from "@mui/material";

const DEFAULT_EMOJI_OPTIONS = [
  {
    emoji: Rocket,
    label: "rocket",
  },
  {
    emoji: Coin,
    label: "coin",
  },
]

function Test() {
  return (
    <>
      {DEFAULT_EMOJI_OPTIONS.map(({ emoji,label }, idx) => (
        <div  key={idx}>
          <div>
            <SvgIcon color="grey.light" component={emoji} viewBox="0 0 64 64" 
                  sx={{ fontSize: 25 }} />    
            <h2>{label}</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </>
  )
}

export default Test;
```

If you want to use img, you can archive by two ways.

```
import Coin from "../assets/emojiIcons/coin.svg";

const DEFAULT_EMOJI_OPTIONS = [
  {
    emoji: Coin,
    label: "coin",
  },
//...
];

const EmojiSection = () => {
  return (
    <div className="text-white border-2 border-gray-800 rounded p-3 my-8 max-w-xs mx-auto">
      {DEFAULT_EMOJI_OPTIONS.map((emoji) => (
          <img src={emoji.emoji} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

or

```
const DEFAULT_EMOJI_OPTIONS = [
  {
    emoji: "../assets/emojiIcons/coin.svg",
    label: "coin",
  },
//...
];

const EmojiSection = () => {
  return (
    <div className="text-white border-2 border-gray-800 rounded p-3 my-8 max-w-xs mx-auto">
      {DEFAULT_EMOJI_OPTIONS.map((emoji) => (
          <img src={required(emoji.emoji)} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thanks for very detailed solution. I'm not using Mui, using tailwindcss